# Git freezes on help commands

Tags: windows, git, google-chrome

I have git (v1.7.4) for windows (msysgit) installed on two different machines, both XP and Vista.  It works fine, with one exception.

When I write "git help" or trigger any "help" commands, the commandline freezes for ~60 seconds, and THEN the webbrowser opens a page with the correspondinge help text.

Why this huge delay?!  Anybody else experience this problem?  My webbrowser is Chrome by default, but I'm not sure if this is the problem.

I may add, that *after* the inital freeze, it solves itself, and every subsequent help command runs flawless. Of course, after a reboot, or possibly enough time, the problem emerges again.

Thanks

EDIT:

Based on feedback I tried the following commands with GIT_TRACE=1

```
C:\Users\zzz\Development\Bloomberg>git web--browse http://google.com
trace: exec: 'git-web--browse' 'http://google.com'
trace: run_command: 'git-web--browse' 'http://google.com'
setup: git_dir: .git
setup: worktree: C:/Users/zzz/Development/Bloomberg
setup: cwd: C:/Users/zzz/Development/Bloomberg
setup: prefix: (null)
trace: built-in: git 'config' 'web.browser'
setup: git_dir: .git
setup: worktree: C:/Users/zzz/Development/Bloomberg
setup: cwd: C:/Users/zzz/Development/Bloomberg
setup: prefix: (null)
trace: built-in: git 'config' 'browser.start.path'

C:\Users\zzz\Development\Bloomberg>git sutatus
trace: exec: 'git-sutatus'
trace: run_command: 'git-sutatus'
*********** FREEZES FOR ~30 SECONDS*************
git: 'sutatus' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
        status
```

However, I'm not very much wiser. Again, after this initail "freeze", the same command responds instantly again.

Comment: I'm using IE as default browser and it's the same behavior here...

Comment: It might be worth adding to your question the results of `set GIT_TRACE=1` and then `git web--browse http://www.google.com` since that seems to be the recommended information to add to bug reports about git help with msysgit.

Comment: When you are reporting a fault in any program, you need to specify the version of the program in question. 'git version' will tell you.

Comment: it is "git version 1.7.4.msysgit.0"  Chrome is v10.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of msysgit are you using?

The [issue 445](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=445) is all about those "delays", but it concludes with:

> Upgrading to Git-1.7.3.1-preview20101002 solved this problem for me.

And indeed I don't see any delay with msysgit1.7.4.0, on WXp or Windows Server2008 (for the two servers at work where I use msysgit).

Otherwise, [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223092/mark-longair)'s suggestions stands:

> Git has it's own tool called "`git web--browse`" that invokes the web-browser.
>   Set the environment `GIT_TRACE` to 1 to see what processes are started, and with what 
>   command-lines.

The mentioned workaround (for 1.7.0.2 version for instance):

> As temporary workaround one can rename all `git-<command>.html` to `git<command>.html` in his `<Git>\doc\git\html` directory.
>   I had the same problem on Git-1.7.0.2-preview20100309.exe and this workaround fixes the 
>   problem.

Comment: I use the following version:
"git --version": git version 1.7.4.msysgit.0

Comment: @VonC How can a ssh filtering trigger a freeze when you write "git status --help" ?

Comment: @Sideshow: sorry, that was a comment for another question: I mixed-up both questions when posting my previous comment ;)

Comment: This answer contained some interesting information, though it didn't fully solve the original problem,  thanks anyway for your effort.

Comment: Nope, the problem still remains. I guess this is something for the git buglists.  It is not a big problem, just annoying :(